# Only fire off Blob trigger function on update

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-blob-trigger

I'm trying to set up a blob trigger function that **only triggers on a blob update**. Looking at the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) I've only been able to figure out the example that triggers on a create and update. I haven't found anywhere that gives an example of how to specify when it fires off the trigger. Is there a way to specify it to only trigger when a blob is updated and not created? Like an attribute or something?

```
[Function("BlobTrigger")]
public void Run([BlobTrigger("blob/{name}", Connection = "")] string myBlob, string name)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {myBlob}");
}
```

Comment: I dont think it is supported. you could always get the creation and modification date and compare that ? Not sure if that would work.

Comment: Not related but there are some limitation regarding the default blob trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#polling. another approch is to use eventgrid trigger: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-event-grid-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 0):

One of the workarounds is to use logic apps's `When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)` trigger. Where the workflow gets triggered whenever the blob gets modified. In the workflow, you can add the Azure function's HTTP trigger and make the Azure function trigger everytime a blob gets created or updated. Below is the flow of logic app.

[image]

### RESULTS:

**In my logic App**

[image]

**In my Function App**

[image]

Comment: In the logic app is there an option to only trigger on a blob update? In your screenshot it says when a blob is added or modified. I don't want this trigger running on blob creation

Comment: @dustinos3 As of now there is no trigger which only triggers only when blob is modified but triggers when created / modified